# How do I get multiple clients to connect to the same source in python?

Tags: python, sockets, clients

I made a class in python that has a socket in it. When I try to run multiple instances of the same class I get this error:

```
error: [Errno 10056] A connect request was made on an already connected socket
```

I can see what the error is saying, but I though the classes were independent of each other when they run. So it wouldn't interfere.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
class Bot():

    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 6667
    s = socket.socket()

    def Connect(self):

        self.s.connect((self.HOST, self.PORT))
```

Then when I create the bots:

```
bots = []

def Setup_Bot():

    global bots

    _bot = Bot()

    _bot.Connect()

    bots.append(_bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in range(5):

        Setup_Bot()

        sleep(1)

    print "Done Setting Up"
```

How would I be able to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the socket `s` an instance variable instead of setting it on the class. All your Bot instances now share the same class attributes and thus, the same socket.

```
class Bot():
    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 6667

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = socket.socket()

    def Connect(self):
        self.s.connect((self.HOST, self.PORT))
```